# Showing Sum through JLabel

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jlabel, jtextfield

I'm a newbie to java, i just want to make a simple JFrame which takes two numbers as input through JtextFields, sum them and return the answer through JLabel... but it simply doesn't do it what it suppose to do, here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.util.*;
public class gUi extends JFrame {
    private JLabel lbl;
    private JLabel lbl2;
    private JLabel lbl3;
    private JTextField tb;
    private JTextField tb1;
    private int num1;
    private int num2;
        public gUi(){
        super("Sum Dialog");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        lbl = new JLabel("1st Number:");
        add(lbl);
        tb = new JTextField(15);
        add(tb);
        tb.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
         num1 = Integer.parseInt(tb.getText());
        }
        });
        lbl2 = new JLabel("2nd Number");
        add(lbl2);
        tb1= new JTextField(15);
        tb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event ){
                num2= Integer.parseInt(tb1.getText());
            }
        });

        add(tb1);
        int sum= num1+num2;
        String ssum = Integer.toString(sum);
        lbl3 = new JLabel();
        lbl3.setText(ssum);
        add(lbl3);      
    }
    }

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        gUi g =new gUi();
        g.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        g.setVisible(true);
        g.setSize(180, 160);


    }

}
```

It Compiles Alright but not showing sum through JLabel when I put some intergers
through Textfields...
I am having this problem for a week and tried different things that I know so far but problem persists...

Comment: `int sum= num1+num2;` This piece of code will execute "immediately" and only once, and `num1` and `num2` are still `0`. The sum has to always be recalculated in your `actionPerformed` methods as well as the text of the sum label.

Comment: Hint: learn about java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase; always. And avoid using "abbreviations" within your names, even "AddingNumbersFrame" or something like that would be more telling than "gUI".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Have a look at the code below(includes comments):

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 * Shows a Stage that has two text Fields
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class UserInterface extends JFrame {

    private JLabel label1;
    private JLabel label2;
    private JLabel label3;
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JTextField textField2;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public UserInterface() {
        super("Sum Dialog");

        // Layout
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // 1st JLabel
        label1 = new JLabel("1st Number:");
        add(label1);
        textField1 = new JTextField(15);
        add(textField1);

        // 2 second JLabel
        label2 = new JLabel("2nd Number");
        add(label2);
        textField2 = new JTextField(15);
        add(textField2);

        // 3 third label
        label3 = new JLabel();
        label3.setSize(200, 30);
        add(label3);

        JButton button = new JButton("Calculate");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                // calculate the sum when the Button is pressed
                int sum = Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText());
                label3.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
            }
        });
        add(button);

    }

    /**
     * Main method of the application
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserInterface main = new UserInterface();
        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        main.setVisible(true);
        main.setSize(180, 160);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much GoXR3Plus! all of You people are very helpful... I really Appreciate it... it helped a lot.....

Comment: @Waleed Sagher :) After using Swing you should pass on JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt put action listeners on your textfields (well, of course you can; but there are other options here).

You could add a button to your frame, maybe with the text "add". And whenever that button is **clicked**, you fetch the two values, add them; and push them into that third textfield.

As of now, your code is computing the sum of 0+0 only once; while your constructor is invoked. Instead, you have to make sure that this computation happens "later on" - when the user asks for it to happen!

But for the record: if you put the **same** action listener on your text fields, that would work, too. If that action listener simply fetches **both** labels, adds them, and puts the sum into field number 3.

Comment: You are very welcome. You might want to check for the updates I made to my answer. And of course: dont forget to accept that answer you think helped the most.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a JLabel and setted its initial value to 0 (because initially both num1 & num2 are 0 ). What you need is to refresh the JLabel(recalculate & display the current sum in action performed method).

E.g.

```
private void updateSum() {
    lbl3.setText(String.valueOf(num1+num2));
}
```

And invoke it in action listener of textfield 1

```
tb.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
         num1 = Integer.parseInt(tb.getText());
            updateSum();

        }
        });
```

and textfield 2

```
tb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event ){
                num2= Integer.parseInt(tb1.getText());
                updateSum();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir! with the help of you guys i hope i will learn quickly.... thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helps :). Remember you can always upvote the answers which you find useful